# Merging of Elements in Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame something like below:

[image: DataFrame]

I want to merge it to be similar to the below format:

[image: Changed Dataframe]

Please someone let me know how to achieve it. This is just a sample and I want to do it for N number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to merge all your columns into one. You can do the following:

1. First create a new empty dataframe:

   ```
   merged_df = pd.DataFrame()
   ```
2. Then, assign the following to the dataframe created in previous step:

   ```
   df1['All_Merged'] = df[df.columns[:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
   ```

Let's suppose your dataframe looked like this:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
```

Your output will look like :

```
All_Merged
0   1,2,3
1   4,5,6
2   7,8,9
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. This was a demo Dataframe. I will implement it in original code with 70 columns and hope it should work.

Comment: Glad to help. It will be great if you can accept my answer @SurajSingh.

Comment: Hi. Please let me know how to accept this answer

Comment: Following link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers